# How do I pass a shared pointer to a cublas function?

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas, gpu-shared-memory

I'm trying to run a cublas function from within a kernel in the following way:

```
__device__ void doLinear(const float *W,const float *input, unsigned i, float *out, unsigned o) {
    unsigned idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

    const float alpha = 1.0f;
    const float beta = 0.0f;

    if(idx == 0) {
        cublasHandle_t cnpHandle;
        cublasStatus_t status = cublasCreate(&cnpHandle);
        cublasSgemv(cnpHandle, CUBLAS_OP_N, o, i, &alpha, W, 1, input, 1, &beta, out, 1);
    }
    __syncthreads();
}
```

This function works perfectly well if the `input` pointer is allocated using cudaMalloc.

My issue is, if the `input` pointer actually points to some shared memory, that contains data generated from within the kernel, I get the error:

```
CUDA_EXCEPTION_14 - Warp Illegal address
```

Is it not possible to pass pointers to shared memory to a cuBLAS function being called from a kernel?

What is the correct way to allocate my memory here? (At the moment I'm just doing another `cudaMalloc` and using that as my 'shared' memory, but it's making me feel a bit dirty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass shared memory to a CUBLAS device API routine because it [violates the CUDA dynamic parallelism memory model](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#execution-environment-and-memory-model) on which device side CUBLAS is based. The best you can do is use `malloc()` or `new` to allocate thread local memory on the runtime heap for the CUBLAS routine to use, or a portion of an *a priori* allocated buffer allocated with one of the host side APIs (as you are presently doing).